# Element position bug in "Privilege" FAQ in Google Chrome

Tags: bug, css, design

From `chrome://version`:

```
Google Chrome   19.0.1077.3 (Official Build 128359) dev
OS              Linux
WebKit          536.4 (@111590)
```

The following happens on https://superuser.com/privileges/edit in Google Chrome (tested in Opera 11.62: does not happen there):

[image: Element position bug.]

The "100%" marker for "edit questions and answers" won't fit on the clarification page for this privilege where the description gets boldfaced. It thus renders on the line below and makes the next two percentage entries also appear out of place.

This also happens for e.g. "remove new user restrictions", "cast close and reopen votes" and the other description pages with the longest names.

Comment: @slhck: I just restarted and got the new version as well - the exact same as you described, and I still see the issue. Perhaps a platform issue.

Answer (score 5):

From the screenshot, one can see that the font is something ricidulously wide. It's actually one of the fonts explicitly specified in the CSS (and not a generic `sans-serif` fallback for people that have no fonts), *DejaVu Sans Bold*, and therefore **a legitimate bug**.

It specifies the font selection `Arial, 'Liberation Sans', 'DejaVu Sans', sans-serif` for the bold element in the sidebar. Verify using  `$('.related strong).css('font-family')`.

---

If you have DejaVu Sans installed ([download here](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download)), you can experience this using the following code snippet:

```
$('.related strong').css('font-family', 'DejaVu Sans')
```

Enter into your browser's JavaScript console, or prepend `javascript:` and enter into the address bar.

[image]

Note how the links are a different font from the user's screenshot, since I changed only the style of the bold element.

---

Of course, in the meantime, just get Liberation Sans (e.g. from [here](https://fedorahosted.org/liberation-fonts/)), which looks almost like Arial, and enjoy nicely aligned text.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, but then it should be definitely reconsidered. Many Linux users don't have Arial by default.

Answer (score 0):

As [slhck mentions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4711/element-position-bug-in-privilege-faq-in-google-chrome#comment12011_4711) beta/dev versions of browsers aren't supported. If you can reproduce this on the stable build, do let us know how.